# Creating a row with two columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following code I was attempting to create a row with two columns where one each section should belong to a column. Could not succeed.

```
    <div class="container">
       <section>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <section>
                       <h2>THIS is heading 2.1</h2>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi!</p>
                   </section>

                   <section>
                       <h2>THIS is heading 2.2</h2>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi!</p>
                   </section>
                </div>    
        </div><!-- row -->
       </section> 
   </div><!-- end of container -->
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you want a section to belong to a column, then insert the section into the column. Repeat the step for the second section.

You can have two columns in a row by having this logic:

```
row
  column
    section
  column
    section
```

Final code:

```
<div class="container">
   <section>
       <div class="row">
       <!----   First section in the first column      --------->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               <section>
                   <h2>THIS is heading 2.1</h2>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi!</p>
               </section>
            </div>

       <!----   Second section in the second column      --------->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               <section>
                   <h2>THIS is heading 2.2</h2>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi!</p>
               </section>
            </div>    
    </div><!-- row -->
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have to use `div` for multiple columns use `section` inside `div`.

```
   <div class="row">
   <!--   First section --->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <section>
               <h1>first section</h1>  
           </section>
        </div>

   <!--  Second section -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <section>
               <h1>second section</h1>      
           </section>
        </div>    
  </div>
```